# How to swap two objects stored inside a bidimensional list in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a bidimensional list that looks something like this:

```
public List<List<Tile>> a = new List<List<Tile>>();
```

These elements are displayed on screen and can be swapped by the user. What I want to do is swap those elements so the list points to the right element after the swap.
I tried doing a simple temporary variable swap suggested by other posts, but that can't seem to get it to work:

```
Tile auxFirst = a[movedTile1.y][movedTile1.x];
a[movedTile1.y][movedTile1.x] = a[movedTile2.y][movedTile2.x];
a[movedTile2.y][movedTile2.x] = auxFirst;
```

I mainly use C++ so I don't think I fully understood how references work in C#. I tried viewing this problem as swapping two pointers, but I may be wrong.
Is there any way I can swap the 2 list items?
If I am approaching this the wrong way, please tell me and help me modify my code.

Comment: The code looks okay to me. You're right that you're just swapping references. In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: have you defined the size of all List?

Comment: Why are you using lists? Looks like you are trying to model coordinates on the screen.

Comment: how are you checking that it doesn't work? If you are checking the value of `movedTile1` or `movedTile2` then they will stay the same until you reassign them.

Comment: I apologize for not responding in time. So the idea is after I swap two tiles, I want to check if I have 3 or more tiles of the same type in a row, similar to a game like candy crush. The check function seems to work fine when I have 3 tiles in a row already and move some random tile, but if I have 2 tiles and move another one to make them 3 in a row, it won't detect them. That's why I'm thinking there is a problem with the swapping. I could attach some of the code, if that would help.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot I thought storing references to other scripts was better with lists, is it better or possible to use normal arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the swapping was right, but I forgot to swap the position coordinates inside the referenced tiles, so when I clicked one of the swapped tiles it would select the other one.
Also, the function that I wrote for checking the tiles was incomplete, so I fixed it.
Here are the bits I added before swapping the elements in the list:

```
coordinates auxPos = movedTile1;
a[movedTile1.y][movedTile1.x].setPosition(movedTile2.x, movedTile2.y);
a[movedTile2.y][movedTile2.x].setPosition(auxPos.x, auxPos.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Lists<> in C# can be indexed as an array, so the following example should apply with the desired Type. The exchange does not use an auxiliary variable:

```cs
int[,] a = {
    { 13, 10, 35, 30},
    { 10, 08, 30, 15},
    { 35, 30, 07, 30},
    { 30, 15, 30, 17},
};
Console.WriteLine("a[1,1] = {0}", a[1, 1]); // 8
Console.WriteLine("a[3,3] = {0}", a[3, 3]); // 17

SwapWithTuple(ref a[1,1], ref a[3,3]);

Console.WriteLine("a[1,1] = {0}", a[1, 1]); // 17
Console.WriteLine("a[3,3] = {0}", a[3, 3]); // 8

static void SwapWithTuple(ref int x, ref int y)
{
    (x, y) = (y, x);
}
```